# Angular - validating data driven forms with custom components

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I've a form with a custom file upload component. Dependent on server data I may need multiple components on the same page.

I'm struggling to get the validation working.  I.E. the "isInvalid" function within the custom form component.

```
get isInvalid(): boolean {
  const formEl = this.form.get('inputFile');
  if (!formEl) {
    return true;
  }

  return formEl.touched && formEl.invalid;
}
```

This cant be some kind of unsolved problem but I've asked a few people in my network and we couldn't figure out how to get it working.  Can anyone suggest either a better approach to making this work or some changes to my code please?

I've included a stackblitz to demonstrate the problem: which is that my custom component validation seems to have no idea who/where it is in relation to the form.  What's interesting is that I can delete/add files to the form itself without problem.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-formarray-dynamic-forms-7b7vfn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finput-file%2Finput-file.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's something wrong in your upload component. You can look at code below:

**Use `@Input() formControlName` in your custom component**

```js
@Input() formControlName: string
```

After that, you can look at your custom component constructor:

**Your constructor**

```js
constructor(private rootFormGroup: FormGroupDirective) {}
```

You can change that constructor with code below:

```js
constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}
```

After that, in your `ngOnInit` you can change initialization `form` like this:

```js
this.form = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
```

And in your `isValid` and `isInvalid` you can change const `formEl` with code below:

```js
const formEl = this.form.get(this.formControlName);
```

For final code in your html you can try with code below:

```html
<!-- No File uploaded yet -->
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="" *ngIf="!file" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
    <label [for]="id" class="" (click)="$event.preventDefault()">
      <strong>{{ inputLabel }}</strong>
    </label>
    <!-- Plus Icon -->
  </div>
  <input
    type="file"
    [name]="id"
    [id]="id"
    class="hidden"
    (change)="onFileSelected($event.target)"
    accept="image/*,.pdf"
    [formControlName]="formControlName"
    #fileUpload
  />
  <!-- If file exists -->
  <div class="" *ngIf="file" (click)="removeFile($event.target)">
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <strong class="text-sm">{{ inputLabel }}</strong>
        <span class="">{{ fileName }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Delete Icon -->
  </div>
  <div
    class="error"
    *ngIf="fileSizeError || isInvalid"
    style="margin-bottom:10px;"
  >
    Please upload a file (max. 5MB)
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

For example you can look at here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-we2x34